# Both .woff and .woff2 version are being loaded on live version of site but not on localhost

Tags: next.js, google-webfonts

We're trying to deal with a large font file download (Noto-sans, ~4MB). We're using Google Fonts to get the font:

```
      <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+JP:wght@400;500;700&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet"
      />
```

On localhost, it seems like Google Fonts is only downloading the pieces of the font we actually need (in a bunch of small chunks, totaling about 800kB). These small chunks are all .woff2. However, on live, in addition to all these small woff2 chunks being downloaded, a large ~4MB noto sans woff file is also being downloaded!

We are using Next.js (not sure if this is related or not).

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Localhost:
[image: localhost]

Live (the top ~4MB .woff file is noto-sans, the other .woff is a different smaller font):
[image]

Comment: Recently Next introduced font optimization: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/font-optimization
I have just noticed that Next inlines both a woff and a woof2 even though the Google Font endpoint only lists woff2.
Can you see this inlined in your DOM?